# Argmax with no duplicates constraint numpy - fuzzy string matching

Tags: string, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, fuzzy-comparison

I have two lists of strings, one called `l1` the other `l2`. I am interested to find for each string in `l1`, the best matching string in `l2` (but not the other way around i.e. I only care about the strings in `l1`). I know that there are no perfect matches. I use the jaro-winkler score to calculate the similarity of each string, using the jellyfish module.

In order to do this, I create a matrix of all the jaro-winkler scores and then find the maximum values for each point in the maxtrix. However, the problem is that sometimes the string from `l2` might be the best match for more than one string from `l1` and I want to prevent this.

Is there some way to optimize the argmax method such that the maximum index position can only appear in the resulting matrix once?

For the sake of an example, tow lists and the subsequent code are below:

```
l1 = ['skinnycorebrokenblack184567', 'promtex2365h6', 'lovelinen940770', 'promtex2365h1', 'lovetrs844705', 
      'lovetrs844704', 'bennttrs49655', 'stella55900', 'kaxsprassel55250', 'smurfbs185573', 'kaxsprassel55880', 
      'victoriacort182062', 'juliatreggings916531', 'juliatreggings916530', 'milo63624505', 'promtex2365s2', 
      'promtex2365s1', 'promtex2365s6', 'promtex2365s4', 'stantwill160810', 'topazchini51081', 'topazchini51087',
      'juliatreggings187109', 'hansentrs50924', '2454s1ladiesjeanscolure', 'promtex2365h2']
l2 = ['stannewtwill160810', 'stellatrs55900', 'jennyhigh352300', 'victoriacort180565', 
      'mistylowribsatins818820202031', 'lovelinen940771', 'kaxsprasseltrs55250', 'milo63626624', 'lovetrs844702',
      'sarabootcuts842887019398270', 'sarabootcuts84288701939', 'victoriacords81805848817', 
      'ladiesjeanscolouredxxl2454s340999', 'julliatregging1871168817', 'logandrawstringpants92686705656', 
      '72480', 'victoriacords85203408817', 'julliatregging9673907817', 'lilypoplin9418412031', 'stellatrs56023',
      'tysontrs50626', 'bolttrousers51370', 'bellamystripe184539', 'tenrhino63602214', 'kidsthermotrousers2365h1',
      'bennytrouser53648', 'bluerinse070201072', 'topazchino51077', 'slimclassicblack674220203128999', 
      'milo63603812', 'milo63603813', 'milo63603814', 'slimclassicblack6742202031', 'lilypoplin9418402031', 
      'julliatregging9673917817', 'smurfjr185606', 'sarabootcuts81884571939', 'julliatregging9165318817']

#create the matrix
mat = np.matrix([[jf.jaro_distance(str(st1), str(st2)) 
              if jf.jaro_distance(str(st1), str(st2)) > 0.85 else 0 
              for st2 in l2] for st1 in l1])

#get max values
mat_max = (mat.argmax(1))

#create match dictionary
match_dict = {}
for x in xrange(len(mat_max)):
    if int(mat_max[x]):
        match_dict[styles[x]] = s2[int(mat_max[x])]
```

In the above example notice that `'topazchino51077'` from `l2` is matched twice against strings from `l1`. This is exactly what I hope to prevent. The string from l2 should be matched against the best match.

Answer (score 1):

You can model your problem in terms of the classical [*stable marriage problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). In your problem, pair-wise matching preferences are given by the `jaro_distance` of two strings; and we want to match every string in `l1` to the closest string in `l2` *unless* that string is already paired with  another from `l1` with more similarity.

The core of the algorithm is provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem#Algorithm). And this is a possible implementation:

```
xs = np.array([[jf.jaro_distance(x, y) for y in l2] for x in l1])
order = np.argsort(xs, axis=1)

FREE = -1 # special value to indicate no match yet
match = FREE * np.ones(len(l1), dtype=np.int_)
jnext = len(l2) * np.ones(len(l1), dtype=np.int_)

# reverse match: if string in l2 is matched to a string in  l1
rev_match = FREE * np.ones(len(l2), dtype=np.int_)

while(np.any(match == FREE)): # while there is an un-matched string
    i = np.where(match == FREE)[0][0] # take the first un-matched index
    jnext[i] -= 1
    j = order[i, jnext[i]] # next l2 string that l1[i] will be matched against
    if rev_match[j] == FREE:  # l2[j] is free, pair i & j together
        rev_match[j], match[i] = i, j
        print('{:30} --> {}'.format(l1[i], l2[j]))
    else: # l2[j] is already paired
        l = rev_match[j] # current l1 string that l2[j] is paired with
        if xs[l, j] < xs[i, j]:  # l2[j] is more similar to l1[i] than l1[l]
            match[l] = FREE      # unpair l & j, and pair i & j
            rev_match[j], match[i] = i, j
            print('{:30} -/- {}'.format(l1[l], l2[j]))
            print('{:30} --> {}'.format(l1[i], l2[j]))
```

To see the final matching:

```
for i, w in enumerate(l1):
    print('{:30} {}'.format(w, l2[match[i]]))
```

As you see, in this solution `'topazchino51077'` is *only* paired with `'topazchini51087'`, because those two are more similar:

```
>>> jf.jaro_distance('topazchini51087', 'topazchino51077')
0.9111
>>> jf.jaro_distance('topazchini51081', 'topazchino51077')
0.8667
```

Comment: This is awesome. I will need to process a bit what's going on, and add a condition that there should be no match if the score is less than 0.85 to prevent spurious matches.

Comment: In fact I can just add this to the final loop through l1: `if xs[l1.index(w), l2.index(l2[match[i]])] > 0.85:` works a treat!